# In App Purchase restoring not working in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I am implementing in app purchase in my app for removing ads from my app.

First time I load the app, did the purchase for remove ads -> Payment was successful and my logic was working perfectly for removing the ads at that time without closing the app.

Next time I opened the app -> called restore purchases, but the purchase I made just before for removing ads is not coming. I am doing this in the alpha testing mode.

Using the below code I am not getting the "remove_ads" is already purchased for the second time.

```
Purchase removeAdsPurchase = inventory.getPurchase("remove_ads");
```

Is this because in the Alpha testing mode GOOGLE will not save the purchased data.

Should I code assuming the purchase will be saved on production.

Comment: Try to put in Beta testing...

Comment: I have found the answer. thankyou.